# Understanding Electric Fields Lines and how they show ‘like’ charges repelling

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electrons

I understand how electric field lines are suppose to be drawn, and why they are drawn from +Q to -Q and all that. What im wondering is how electric field lines explain why like charges repel? In the instance of placing a test charge q in an electric field around two +Q’s the resultant force is in line with the electric field lines. But then why, if we didnt consider a test charge but just considered our two +Q’s, the “resultant force” they would both experience does not line up with the electric field lines of the charge that is effecting it? Am I missing something fundamentally here? If so Can you help me visualize? Cheers[image][image]

Answer (score 7):

In the pictures like yours, the density of lines is proportional to the local field strength. When two opposite charges come close you see how field lines have to squish to make way for each other (in the absence of opposite charges those lines cannot terminate and need to find their way to infinity) consequently forming regions of increased line density. Since the total energy of the field is
$$\mathcal{E} = \int dV\,  \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 \left|\vec{E}(\vec{r})\right|^{2},$$
this gives rise to an increase of total energy, and hence repulsion.

Comment: How does an increase in total energy lead to repulsion?

Comment: If a change in position leads to change in the total energy of a system (for what ever reason), this for all practical purposes is indistinguishable from the presence of a force on the object whose coordinate is in question (take "entropy force" on a rubber band as a good counter-intuitive example: https://chem.washington.edu/lecture-demos/entropy-rubber-band).

Answer (score 5):

The early experimenters studying electrostatics gave electric field lines a series of properties which then enabled them to predict what might happen in a given situation.

Electric field lines,

- start on a positive charge and finish on a negative charge or at
  infinity,
- point in the direction of the force on a positive charge,
- are in a state of tension,
- repel one another
- never cross
- are
  closer together in a region where the electric field is stronger
- are at right angles to the surface of a conductor.

So in your diagrams you could say that the *field lines are repelling one another* and that is why the charges are repelling one another.

With opposite charge there would be *field lines between the charges in a state of tension* and that is why the charges attract one another.

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to answer my question! I did not think of electric field lines being in"tension"...where have you read that before? I would love to learn more!

Comment: @Jake The idea of tension is used to “explain” attraction.

Comment: Ahhh I understand…thank you